# Динамическая замена xtype

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

Мне нужно динамически заменить пользовательский `xtype` на другой. Т.е. есть список новостей, при нажатии на одну из них вместо списка на панели должна появится подробно выбранная новость. Все новости выводятся из базы через цикл `<tpl for=".">`. Я попробовал сделать через `onclick` открыть новость следующим способом, но ничего не выходит:

```
onclick="layout.getComponent(newsPanel).add(currentnew)"
```

`newsPanel` - это id итема на странице, а `currentnew` - это мой `xtype`. К тому же пока не знаю как передать `id` конкретной новости. Есть идеи как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика такая: у компонента что хотим показать делаем свойство `hidden: true`. Далее, при клике вызываем функцию в контроллере (у меня `MVC`), которая скрывает старый компонент и показывает новый через `componentId.setVisible(bool);`. И в конце при помощи `JQuery` меняем значения переменных которые заполняют поля: `$(".fieldClass").text(store.variable);`. Не забудьте поправить все переменные и проинициализировать их.